# Twig, Symfony2: Extend template conditionally from same action

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my **base.html.twig** file under one div section the render function is called on the **Session Controller** and **editAction**, which in turn renders **edit.html.twig**:

```
<div class="container">
    {{ render(controller("DefaultBundle:Session:edit", {'id':session.id})) }}
</div>
```

The **edit.html.twig**:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    <div>
        <p>Fill in the form below to change the data:</p>
        <div class="session_form">
            {{ form_label(form.title) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.title) }}

            <div id="form_options">
                {{ form_rest(form) }}
            </div>
            <button class="btnSave">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

This all works fine, however, in some circumstances the edit.html.twig file will be displayed to edit an entity in a form, based on the route of the editAction, where as above it can be rendered directly without the need of the route for the editAction. This means no template will be inherited and it will be a plain style with a basic form. I could use ***"{% extends 'DefaultBundle::base.html.twig' %}"*** however, this means that sometimes the template will essentially be displayed twice on a page, which isn't pretty, or practical. Is there a way of extending the base.html.twig depending on whether the render(controller{}) is used or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a variable from the controller or a global twig variable from a listener to your view indicating wether to extend the template.

Then combine an ternary if-condition with `extends`.

```
{% extends standalone ? "minimum.html" : "DefaultBundle::base.html.twig" %}
```

... where minimum can be a template containing only a `content` block but the file has to exist.

Comment: This won't work. The variable will be passed each time as the editAction is always called, therefore result in either no template rendering, or both.

Comment: you just have to check the `kernel.request` event if `$event->getRequestType()` is equal to `HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST` or `HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST` then pass the variable as true or false ... but your question was **Is there a way of extending the base.html.twig depending on whether the render(controller{}) is used or not?** which my answer suits :)

Comment: `{% if ... %}` there won't affect `{% extends %}`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, however using the kernel.request seems to always output true?

Comment: could you add your current implementation to the question?